# CHROME -EXTENSIONS: How can I run message passing multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a project which produces a Chrome extension. In a background page I have a function named `checkingProcess`. This function is executed when a new tab is opened or a tab is updated. (I tried to catch the change of URL here.)

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  checkingProcess(activeInfo.tabId)
})

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  checkingProcess(tab.id)
})
```

Then, in the `checkingProcess` function, I have some functions for the data handling and API calls. Then I tried to receive a message that comes from popup. This message represents that the popup was opened by the user.

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.msg === 'popup_opened') {
      sendResponse({
        matches_length: response['matches'].length,
        hostname: host,
      })
    }
    chrome.runtime.lastError
  })
```

After that, it sends a response to the popup. In the popup, I listen to the message and use the response in the popup.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: 'popup_opened' }, (res) => {
      setHostname(res['hostname'])
      setMatchesLength(res['matches_length'])
      console.log(res['hostname'], 'burası')
      console.log(res['matches_length'], 'burası')
    })
  }, [])
```

However, I realize that this message process is only executed once, but I need to run it multiple times to access the data in background simultaneously. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your message is only sent once because it's currently setup in a `React.useEffect` with [an empty list of dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects). This means this code will only be run once when your component is mounted. If you want to run it "*multiple times*" you first need to define what this means? Examples are:

- Executing `sendMessage` after a user performs some action, like clicking a button. In that case you don't need `useEffect`. Instead, wire an event handler to that button and perform the `sendMessage` there.
- Executing `sendMessage` after re-render of your component. Simply remove the empty list of dependencies (`[]`) from your `useEffect` method. Note: use this with caution. If you setup your component in a way that it re-renders often, this can quickly turn into a situation where many API calls are made.
- Executing `sendMessage` after some state within your component changes. Add this variable to the list of dependencies: `[loaded]`
- Executing `sendMessage` every 10 seconds. You'll want to use `setInterval` within your `useEffect`, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: 'popup_opened' }, (res) => {
      setHostname(res['hostname'])
      setMatchesLength(res['matches_length'])
      console.log(res['hostname'], 'burası')
      console.log(res['matches_length'], 'burası')
    })
  }, 10000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: I want that when the use open popup, it works again.