# CHROME-EXTENSIONS: How can I run a function for different tabs at the same time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a project that creates a google chrome extension. I have a function. I want that if new tab is `onUpdated` or `onActivated` this function works. Also, I want it works every tab simultaneously. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, (tabs) => {
    Process()
  })
})

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    Process()
  })
})
```

Comment: So, is this a content script or a service worker? Either way, why do you need to query the tabs? If an content script, just add a window event listener. If a background script, then the "onActivated" already passes the tab in its callback (should this run on all tabs or just new or newly activated tab). Regardless, this should work. What's in your manifest and what's your Process() trying to do? ```for (let i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {console.log(`hello world, from activated tab #${tabs[i].id}`)}``` works as expected here.

Comment: @Bobby This is my background script. In my process function there is a webRequest.oncomplete API. When I work it for every tab, this problem shown :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124613/chrome-extensions-chrome-webrequest-onbeforerequest-does-not-finish-the-proce

Comment: Okay, looking at all of your questions in context, including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70066110/chrome-extensions-how-can-i-run-message-passing-multiple-times it seems that the issue might be more likely with React.useEffect or webRequest. The code you have in this question should "work" (although as the Answer below points out, it might be triggering more often than you want it to do and there may be cleaner ways to get there.) You may need to try simplifying more & adding more watches to see if you can isolate your issue and ask again. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will show how to apply same function on tab events `onActivated` and `onActivated` and to apply the function to all tabs on these events. You will want to do this in background service worker.

Create an extension manifest specifying the service worker:

```json
{
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

Next, in background.js script (the service worker), you will want to handle these events. The most basic implementation could look like this, and will call `Process` function on every tab, each time any tab is activated or updated:

```js
function Process(tab) {
    // now do something with each tab
    console.log(`Process tab id ${tab.id}`);
}

function ProcessAllTabs() {
    // do not specify query options to get 
    // all tabs in all windows for current user
    chrome.tabs.query({},
        (tabs) => tabs.map(Process));
}

// register the event listeners
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(ProcessAllTabs);
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(ProcessAllTabs);
```

If you debug this behavior, you will notice the tab update will call the even handler twice as the tab undergoes different update statuses. You may want to be more specific, and perhaps only call `Process` *after* tab has finished updating, or have more information about which event caused `Process` to be called. In that case, a more detailed implementation could look like this:

```js
// name the events
const EventsEnum = {UPDATE: 'update', ACTIVATE: 'activate'};

function Process(tab, eventName) {
    // now do something with each tab:
    console.log(`Process tab id ${tab.id} on ${eventName}`);
}

function ProcessAllTabs(eventName) {
    // do not specify query options to get
    // all tabs in all windows for current user
    chrome.tabs.query({},
        // pass more arguments to Process function
        (tabs) => tabs.map(tab => Process(tab, eventName)));
}

// register the event listeners
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(
    // include event name
    () => ProcessAllTabs(EventsEnum.ACTIVATE));

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tab, changeInfo) => {
    // require that tab update is complete before proceeding
    if (changeInfo.status === "complete") {
        ProcessAllTabs(EventsEnum.UPDATE)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank youuu. However I want to ask another thing because with this way, I couldnt solve the problem. In my ```Process()``` function, there is ```chrome.webRequest.onComplete.addListener``` When I run the Process function, I see the (for example nytimes.com) nytimes resources in google.com. They do not run seperately

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the follow up question. Process can be used to do ~whatever with each tab. webRequest listener can be added independently of tab activate/update events, https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onCompleted